# Wordpress Media Uploads Custom Directory - (Directory names as image sizes)

Tags: php, wordpress

i want to customize the wordpress media uploads folders names as media settings image sizes and when uploading an image the re sized images goes to corresponding folder. For eg:- in my settings i have the following size

```
Thumbnail - 200x200
Medium - 500x375
Large Size - 800x600
```

and i want the media uploads folder as follows

```
/uploads/200x200/
/uploads/500x375/
/uploads/800x600/
```

when uploading the file each re sized  images must go to the corresponding folder. Can anyone help me to sort out this. Thanks